# How to resolve Cannot find module '@angular/router/src/utils/collection' or its corresponding type declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

how can i resolve Error:

```
src/app/metronic/orderByLocation/locationsByOneOrder/locationsByOneOrder.component.ts:7:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router/src/utils/collection' or its corresponding type declarations.m

7 import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/metronic/orderByLocation/update-location/subpoena-options/subpoena-options.component.ts:5:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router/src/utils/collection' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/metronic/orderByLocation/update-location/update-location.component.ts:6:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router/src/utils/collection' or its corresponding type declarations.

6 import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
```

Answer (score 0):

'forEach' is a Javascript / Typescript method and not an angular import. Its a member of the array prototype, therefore you need to call it on the array you want to operate.

1. Remove the import and use as below.

   this.data.foreach(element => {
   doNextTask();
   });

if you want to loop as key and index then as below.

```
this.data.forEach(function callback(value, index) {
   console.log(`${index}: ${value}`);
});
```